# Python troubles saving several pool processed files

Tags: python, threadpool

I need to process some files in praralel.
I'm using pool, but i have troubles saving the pool processed files.
Here is the code:

```
... All imports...

def extract(text_lines):

    line_tr01 = []
    line_tr02 = []
    line_tr03 = []
    line_tr03 = []
    for line in text_lines:
        treatment01 = treatment_a(line, args)
        line_tr01.append(treatment01)
        treatment02 = treatment_b(line, args)
        line_tr02.append(treatment02)
        treatment03 = treatment_c(line, args)
        line_tr03.append(treatment03)
        treatment04 = treatment_d(line, args)
        line_tr04.append(treatment04)


for file in folder:
    text_lines = read_file_into_list(file_path)
    chunk_size=len(text_lines)/6
    divided=[]

    divided.append(text_lines[0:chunk_size])
    divided.append(text_lines[chunk_size:2*chunk_size])
    divided.append(text_lines[2*chunk_size:3*chunk_size])
    divided.append(text_lines[3*chunk_size:4*chunk_size])
    divided.append(text_lines[4*chunk_size:5*chunk_size])
    divided.append(text_lines[5*chunk_size:6*chunk_size])

    lines=[]
    p = Pool(6)
    lines.extend(p.map(extract(text_lines),divided))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    p.terminate()

    line_tr01=lines[0]
    with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(line_tr01, f)
    line_tr02=lines[1]
    with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(line_tr02, f)
    line_tr03=lines[2]
    with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(line_tr03, f)
    line_tr04=lines[3]
    with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(line_tr04, f)
```

Any light on how can I stop overwriting the files
Any help will be welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're saving all of the data in the subprocesses. If you want to aggregate it first, you should return it and then process the file output in your parent process.

Comment: @CJ59 Thanks, I'm saving outside the loop now but still get more than 3 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that when you break stuff into pools, you no longer have the common global namespace that you're currently (ab)using. So let's just rewrite this to pass things properly.

```
def extract(text_lines):
    treatments = dict(tr01=[], tr02=[], tr03=[], tr04=[])
    for line in text_lines:
        treatments['tr01'].append(treatment_a(line, args))
        treatments['tr02'].append(treatment_b(line, args))
        treatments['tr03'].append(treatment_c(line, args))
        treatments['tr04'].append(treatment_d(line, args))
    return treatments

def line_gen(lines, chunk_size=1):
    for i in range(0, len(lines), chunk_size):
        yield lines[i:i + chunk_size]

for file in folder:
    text_lines = read_file_into_list(file_path)
    treatments = dict(tr01=[], tr02=[], tr03=[], tr04=[])
    p = Pool(6)
    for treat_data in p.imap(extract, line_gen(text_lines, chunk_size=int(len(text_lines)/6))):
        for tr, data in treat_data.items():
            treatments[tr].extend(data)

    # Do something with all your data in the treatments dict
```

This should pile up all of the data into a dict called `treatments`, because it returns the data from your child process that's running `extract`, and then you can write out the data in whatever way that you'd like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly!